# How to make cyclone slider images retina ready

Tags: css, retina-display

I'm using cyclone slider in this website: http://www.malithaisouthcenter.com/
in the settings I have an option to setup the width(which I currently set to 1600). now if I want to make the slider images retina ready, what should I do? I know I can make the images retina ready & let them downsample by browsers with this code:

```
.img {
    background-image: url(Retina-image-800x600-2x.png);
    background-size: 400px 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

But the problem is, we are talking about a group of pictures, not just one image.

Answer (score 0):

[retina.js](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) – JAVASCRIPT METHOD

a small JavaScript file which detects @2x images and displays them on retina devices. Download retina.js, and include it in your web page with the following between the tags, or alternatively, place it just before the closing tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/retina.js"></script>
```

MEDIA QUERIES – TARGETING PIXEL RATIO AND RESOLUTION

Media Queries can be used to target retina devices in order to include high res graphics, for example:

```
@media

(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),

(min-resolution: 192dpi) {

/* Retina graphics */

}
```

or

/* CSS for high-resolution devices */

```
@media only screen and (-Webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    .icons {
    background-image: url(Retina-image-800x600-2x.png);
    background-size: 400px 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    }
}
```

or

In webkit-based browsers, `image-set ()` is already supported.

```
.image {    
background: -webkit-image-set( url('path/to/image') 1x, url('path/to/high-res-image') 2x );   
}
```

Comment: but I have a group of images. & there width must be setup through cyclone slider settings. it ll ignore the image size.